# Duistermaat & Kolk's lost chapters on Lie groups

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, book-recommendation

I am reading the book *Lie Groups* by Duistermaat and Kolk.

It is written in the preface that "the text contains references to chapters belonging to a future volume". I could not find this second volume anywhere. Has it been published? Is it available somewhere?

For example, on page 51, they refer to Chapter 14, while the book only has 4 chapters. I would be very much interested to read these additional chapters.

[image]

Comment: Duistermaat died in 2010, and Kolk took early retirement in 2009: http://www.uu.nl/staff/JACKolk/0. The paper *Remembering Johannes J. Duistermaat (1942-2010)*, which can be downloaded from Kolk's website, doesn't seem to mention any interrupted plans for a further volume (but I only skimmed it).

Comment: So why don't you just contact Mr. Kolk? His email address is in the reference.